# Spotify API Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, spotify

I was trying to make a get request to the spotify API using axios in node.js. But, I always end up getting a 400 bad request. Could someone please help me out? The code snippet and the error are pasted below.

```
 app.get('/api/search', async (req, res) => {
        const spotify_search_one = await axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search', {
            headers: { 
                'Authorization': keys.spotifyClientId 
            }, 
            params: {
                q: "face",
                type: "track"
            } 
        });
        console.log(spotify_search_one);
    })
```

The error is as follows

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 400
[0]     at createError (/Users/uddhavbhagat/Desktop/Projects/TuneIn/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
[0]     at settle (/Users/uddhavbhagat/Desktop/Projects/TuneIn/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
[0]     at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/uddhavbhagat/Desktop/Projects/TuneIn/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
[0]     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:322:22)
[0]     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1187:12)
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
[0] (node:12697) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)
```

Comment: try `'Authorization': 'Bearer '+keys.spotifyClientId`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I tried it

Comment: The error changed to a 401 error. Don't know how I could fix that

Comment: spotifyClientId doesn't sound right, it should be a valid access token. See docs: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/

Comment: Is the access token different from the clientID? ClientID is essentially the API Key I made from the developer console

Comment: Yes, Client ID and Access token are different

Comment: Also, should the q and type be written like "q" and "type"? Or it does not matter?

Comment: Also, how should one go about saving the access token? Do we just store the token in a database? Is there a way to not store it in a database and use it?

Answer (score 0):

The error you‘re getting is that the Promise (axios.get) does not have a catch.
Therefore when the api call results in an error, you are not handling it in any way. What about trying it the asynchronous way?
I would send the api call `axios.get(‘URL‘, ...)` and then handle the response with `.then` and `.catch.`

I would suggest the following:

```
axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search', { headers: { 'Authorization': keys.spotifyClientId } })
     .then(response => {
           const spotify_search_one = response.data;
     }).catch(err => {
           console.error(err);
     })
```

This will ask the Spotify-API for the desired data and then execute anything you write in the `.then` when the API-call was successful. The variable `response` contains the data (in this case the search results) which you can get with `response.data`.
If the API-call fails everything in `.catch` will be called. You could print the error or handle it in any other way then.

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu Is this okay?